# Example of an ordered, noncommutative division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

Does there exist a noncommutative division ring $D$ (i. e. a field except that commutativity of multiplication is violated, e. g. the quaternions) which is also an ordered ring?

Since most examples of division rings I am aware of are constructed in a manner very similarto the quaternions and thus not orderable, I would be very curious to see an example of such a ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it a skew Laurent series ring (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring) in the examples section) is such a ring. According to [page 10](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=f15FyZuZ3-4C&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&source=bl&ots=l5mkhqTApW&sig=JgCjAz14eEHR3fauDCcuEzw_oco&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g_pCU9XiKoSM7Qa85IHwCg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) of "A First Course in Noncommutative Rings" by Tsi-Yuen Lam, Hilbert was the first to note this.

Comment: I guess the ordering must be first by the "lower degree," and then lexicographically by coefficient. If that's the case, it's worth noting how this ordering is highly nonArchimedian. All the natural numbers are trapped within the confines of the lower degree $0$ elements, so none of them can reach above things with lower degre 1, 2, etc.